# export specific field from from sharepoint custom list to excel

Tags: export, field-definition, custom-list, hidden, xpath

I'm having custom list (SharePoint 2007)

I need to export the list to Excel file.
So I mark all the field that I want to export.

but I when I export the list I can see:

1. the "Path" field, though that I did not mark this field as field that I want him to  show in the defualt view.
2. some field that I defined as hide field in the default view.

how can I avoid thos thing

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do to ensure that the fields you don't want to see are not exported, is create a view that shows only those fields that you want to see and export that view. As far as the "Path" that field is exported by default, and you will have to manually delete it from the excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Record and format an excel macro to format the list and remove the excess fields after export; see this answer for details: [SharePoint 2007 List export to Excel 2007](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47847/sharepoint-2007-list-export-to-excel-2007/76849#76849)