# Fail to export custom SPList to Excel

Tags: list, excel, list-definition, export

Im trying to export a SharePoint-List(created from a custom Listdefinition) to Excel by using the "Export to Excel"-button on the ribbon. It works when im trying with other default SharePoint-lists like "Tasks" but not with my three lists created from unique listdefinitions.

The error im presented with is “An unexpected error has occurred. Changes to your data cannot be saved”.

The list has less than 50 items so it should not matter.

I have tried from different computers, changing permissions on the list for the user.
Im using Sharepoint 2010 and Office pro x64 Excel.

Would really appreciate someone nudging me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue myself.

Apparently the custom lists columns was both named "Column name" and had the display name "Column name" in the XML-code. The column name should be "Column_name". Sharepoint fills the blank with %20 and this creates my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you marked the fields of data that you want SharePoint to export to excel?

You have to create a view 'telling' excel what columns to export, as far as I know and have seen. This answer may be related to the issue here:

[export specific field from from sharepoint custom list to excel](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17484/export-specific-field-from-from-sharepoint-custom-list-to-excel)

What have you tried so far? What view are you using? Have you tried editing in datasheet view then exporting through that view?

I will experiment more when I have time today. I'll follow up with whatever I find, if I find anything.

Comment: My custom lists uses a standard view with only the lists columns in it. 
Datasheetview work fully with other lists but not with my custom ones. When I try the Datasheet is generated with the right columns but an empty table. I then get an errormessage "Cannot connect to the server at this time, You can continue working with this list, but some data may not be available". 
It seems that this problem is related to the issue when I try to export the list to Excel directly.

Comment: Solved the issue myself.

Apparently the custom lists columns was both named "Column name" and had the display name "Column name" in the XML-code. The column name should be "Column_name". Sharepoint fills the blank with %20 and this creates my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since yesterday this problem has been resolved for us by using the new drop-down in Sharepoint list, select Export > CSV. The issue was with the workbook export option (that used to be the default on the Export button) that downloads the .iqy, however .iqy has access granted via the cloud account, while some of our employees have a different account for onprem installed apps through SCCM, so the licensing for the apps go to the onprem accounts, thus Sharepoint doesn't detect the correct permissions to open that in the Excel application. However by using the CSV export option that is now available in Sharepoint, the data is read and processed with the cloud account when you press the button, and then translated into the app. This process does not require the user to have the same account both on the cloud and locally (in the apps), since it pastes the content that was already copied with the right permissions. Hope it helps someone!